# Setting attributes dynamically along with ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set the `selected` attribute dynamically if the index value matches.

```
<select class="form-control" disabled>
  <option *ngFor="let agency of request.agencyList" [attr.selected]="request.agencyIndex == agency">{{agency}}{{request.agencyIndex}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Object:

```
this.requests = [{
        agencyList: ['Agency 1', 'Agency 2', 'Agency 3'],
        agencyIndex: 1,
        ...
        }]
```

However, its setting all option `selected` attribute to `false`.

Comment: agency is a string, agencyIndex is a number, as I see, request.agencyIndex !== agency

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<select class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let agency of request.agencyList; let index=index;" [selected]="request.agencyIndex == index">
       {{agency}}{{request.agencyIndex}}
   </option>
</select>
```